# segfault after failed call do `GetParentLink`: collada_joint_publisher with diamondback

Tags: rviz, collada, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone!

My name is Ivan, and I have a problem with Ros discussed below:
rviz running with "roslaunch orrosplanning collada_rviz_display.launch model: = barrettwam.dae" to start simulation of the WAM
all display screen but nothing else and throw rviz the following errors:

```
rviz: /opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/robot_model/urdf/src/collada_model_reader.cpp:683: bool urdf::ColladaModelReader::_ExtractKinematicsModel(domKinematics_modelRef, domNodeRef, domPhysics_modelRef, const std::list<urdf::ColladaModelReader::JointAxisBinding, std::allocator<urdf::ColladaModelReader::JointAxisBinding> >&): La declaración `_checkMathML(papplyelt,"apply")' no se cumple.
[rviz-3] process has died [pid 27214, exit code -6].
log files: /home/ivaxxus/.ros/log/03c9da48-61d6-11e0-a0aa-70f1a192dd31/rviz-3*.log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/orrosplanning/collada_joint_publisher.py", line 78, in <module>
    jsp.loop()
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/orrosplanning/collada_joint_publisher.py", line 53, in loop
    if link.GetParentLink() is None:
AttributeError: 'Link' object has no attribute 'GetParentLink'
[collada_joint_publisher-2] process has died [pid 27213, exit code -11].
log files: /home/ivaxxus/.ros/log/03c9da48-61d6-11e0-a0aa-70f1a192dd31/collada_joint_publisher-2*.log
```

And that's not all, I have tested with other models collada_robots, only throw an error here is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/orrosplanning/collada_joint_publisher.py", line 78, in <module>
    jsp.loop()
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/orrosplanning/collada_joint_publisher.py", line 53, in loop
    if link.GetParentLink() is None:
AttributeError: 'Link' object has no attribute 'GetParentLink'
[collada_joint_publisher-2] process has died [pid 27589, exit code -11].
log files: /home/ivaxxus/.ros/log/92315086-61d6-11e0-9589-70f1a192dd31/collada_joint_publisher-2*.log
```

Not what happens, I have a few days trying to solve the problem but I can not.

In case you need my pc is a Toshiba Satellite L655D, with AMD and ATI Mobility RADEON HD 4200 and SO: Ubuntu 10.10

I appreciate the time given
Yours sincerely

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9675/segfault-after-failed-call-do-%60getparentlink%60:-collada_joint_publisher-with-diamondback/) by [Ivan Rojas Jofre](https://answers.ros.org/users/398/ivan-rojas-jofre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2011-04-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of using diamondback version, I had to download and compile the trunk version via SVN from http://www.ros.org/wiki/jsk-ros-pkg

Also had to recompile rviz from source, so it links to newly compiled robot_model library.

---

Originally posted by [Nick Armstrong-Crews](https://answers.ros.org/users/885/nick-armstrong-crews/) with karma: 481 on 2011-07-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you projecting marker fare outside of your workspace x,y,z ?

---

Originally posted by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) with karma: 847 on 2011-04-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1